# React Native: Make a native library

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have made an App and successfully made a bridge and integrated native code.

Now I  want to make a native library in React-Native, which includes ios and android code.
I tried many websites and there isn't much online resource for it.

Right now, 
Everything is working. 
But now I want to make it as an npm module and make the `react-native link` command or `pods` work.
In this process, I already know the npm procedure. But I don't know how the linking works.
Same with android, I want the `react-native link` to work as well.

Is there any resource where I can find a good approach to this.

Comment: You've created a React-native module with Android and IOS codes and you don't know how to use it?

Comment: I have created it in my app, I want it to be used as a package though.

Comment: Do you mean you want to download the package rather than use the NativeModule?

Comment: https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46
For using Cocoapods https://io.bilby91.com/posts/create-react-native-ios-native-module